# Two power supplies meter the same, computer turns on with one but not the other

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, power

I'm trying to diagnose an apparently random sudden power-off problem on a desktop, so I swapped out components until the power supply and mother board were the remaining suspects.

I removed power supply `A` and replaced it with `B`. Power button no longer turns it on. Uh oh. So I did the paper clip jump on `B` and the power supply fan came on, as well as some of the case fans that were still hooked up.

I plugged `A`'s 24 pin and 8 pin into the motherboard, power button makes everything come on like before.

Switched back and plugged `B`'s 24 pin and 8 pin into the motherboard, power button does nothing. Immediately after the paper clip test confirms it has power. Random probing of other wires shows power.

I switched them back and forth a few times to make sure I wasn't missing something. `A` makes fans spin, LEDs turn on the moment power button is pressed. `B` does nothing, indistinguishable from being unplugged.

I volt-metered the 24 and 8 pins of `A` and `B` and got close enough readings: the same ~3.3s, ~5s and ~12s in each pin position between the set of 24 and 8.

The widest discrepancy was `A` having a ~10V reading and `B` reading closer to 12. But `A` is the one that works (other than the initial problem), so that doesn't seem like it explains this.

`A` is 600W, `B` is 650 W.

How do I proceed? With the power supplies I mean

Comment: You are measuring only volts. The amps you can get from the battery are just as important.

Comment: You neglect to describe how you measured the voltages.  Are the measurements while the PSU is powering the mobo, or are the PSU plugs dangling in the air?

Comment: If your PSU caps are stuffed I posit that the voltage could be OK under no load, but not be able to rectify enough under load (or cause power thats not smooth enough)

Comment: @sawdust No, I did not attempt to measure it while it was "powering the mobo" because as far as I can tell it is not, nothing appears to come on. Would I have to hold the power button down to get measurements on that? Or would that result in a shutdown after 3 seconds? Any advice on which pin/voltage level is most useful to monitor when I try this?

Comment: @davidgo It has no difficulty powering five or six fans when they're hooked up, but when the motherboard is in the loop it does nothing, even with the fans. Is that consistent with bad caps?

Comment: I'm not an elected engineer, but I postulate yes because (a) At 6 watts per fan that's a load of only 36 watts - so not much, (b) fans are very tolerant on low voltage and power drops - I'm almost certain fans could even be run on even bridge  rectified AC which would - which would be what a simple ac-dc converter with no caps would look like - unlike CPUs  (c) bad caps are very common - especially in PSU's and (d) your voltmeter tests say very little, because they are not reading distortion/noise - and 10 volts for a 12 volt rail is way out of spec.

Comment: See https://www.evga.com/support/faq/FAQdetails.aspx?faqid=59025

Comment: @davidgo I opened it up, some of the caps are looking bloated. And cramped, I think it's beyond my skills to replace it. Maybe the 10V reading explains my original problem.

Comment: @sawdust With a third, known functional PSU I still had crashes. With the original setup, including the original PSU I quickly ran HWmonitor before it could crash and the values were stable and in range. Is that enough of a load/accurate enough to clear the original PSU of suspicion?

Comment: Presumably PSU `A` is the *"original PSU of suspicion"*?  *"Is that enough ... to clear the original PSU of suspicion?"* -- Not really.  There's always the remote possibly of multiple failures, or a weakness in one component triggers a failure in another.  The confirmation would be to insert the *"original PSU"* in another similar working system, and not have any issues.

Comment: *"Would I have to hold the power button down to get measurements on that?"* -- Ideally you would use an oscilloscope to see the response of the three voltage rails (under a load) when the power button is pressed then released.